# Need an example of Ypsilon usage

Tags: c++, scheme, bytecode, ffi

I started to mess with [Ypsilon](http://code.google.com/p/ypsilon/), which is a C++ implementation of Scheme.

It conforms [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/), features fast garbage collector, supports multi-core CPUs and Unicode but has a **LACK** of documentation, C++ code examples and comments in the code!

Authors provide it as a standalone console application.
My goal is to use it as a scripting engine in an image processing application.

The source code is well structured, but the structure is unfamiliar.
I spent two weeks penetrating it, and here's what I've found out:

1. All communication with outer world is done via C++ structures called
   ports, they correspond to Scheme ports.
2. Virtual machine has 3 ports: IN, OUT and ERROR.
3. Ports can be std-ports (via console), socket-ports,
   bytevector-ports, named-file-ports and custom-ports.
4. Each custom port must provide a filled structure called *handlers*.
5. *Handlers* is a vector containing 6 elements: 1st one is a boolean
   (whether
       port is textual), and other five are function pointers (onRead, onWrite, onSetPos, onGetPos, onClose).

As far as I understand, I need to implement 3 custom ports (IN, OUT and ERROR).
But for now I can't figure out, what are the input parameters of each function (onRead, onWrite, onSetPos, onGetPos, onClose) in *handlers*.

Unfortunately, there is neither example of implementing a custom port no example of following stuff:

1. C++ to Scheme function bindings (provided examples are a bunch of
   .scm-files, still unclear what to do on the C++ side).
2. Compiling and
       running bytecode (via bytevector-ports? But how to compile text to
       bytecode?).

**Summarizing**, if anyone provides a C++ example of any scenario mentioned above, it would significantly save my time.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you tried to contact the project maintainer of the project? It could save you some time.

Comment: @Seki, Yep. They didn't answer.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, from what I can read of the source code, here's how the various handlers get called (this is all unofficial, based purely on source code inspection):

1. Read handler: `(lambda (bv off len))`: takes a bytevector (which your handler will put the read data into), an offset (fixnum), and a length (fixnum). You should read in up to `len` bytes, placing those bytes into `bv` starting at `off`. Return the number of bytes actually read in (as a fixnum).
2. Write handler: `(lambda (bv off len))`: takes a bytevector (which contains the data to write), an offset (fixnum), and a length (fixnum). Grab up to `len` bytes from `bv`, starting at `off`, and write them out. Return the number of bytes actually written (as a fixnum).
3. Get position handler: `(lambda (pos))` (called in text mode only): Allows you to store some data for `pos` so that a future call to the set position handler with the same `pos` value will reset the position back to the current position. Return value ignored.
4. Set position handler: `(lambda (pos))`: Move the current position to the value of `pos`. Return value ignored.
5. Close handler: `(lambda ())`: Close the port. Return value ignored.

Comment: That will help, thank you, @Chris! Are you related to the development of Ypsilon?

Comment: My pleasure. I'm not related at all: I just downloaded Ypsilon after I saw this question and decided to dig around. However, two things helped: 1. I am a committer for Guile (another Scheme implementation) so I do know how Scheme implementations work in general, and 2. I have professional experience in C++, and consider C++ one of my primary languages.

Answer (score 3):

To answer another question you had, about compiling and running "bytecode":

1. To compile an expression, use `compile`. This returns a code object.
2. There is no publicly-exported approach to run this code object. Internally, the code uses `run-vmi`, but you can't access this from outside code.
3. Internally, the only place where compiled code is loaded and used is in its `auto-compile-cache` system.

Have a look at `heap/boot/eval.scm` for details. (Again, this is not an official response, but based purely on personal experimentation and source code inspection.)